# Quarkus test LauncherUtil fails searching for "Listening on:" in logs

Tags: quarkus

I am building a Lambda handler and tests are failing and Quarkus Test is looking for a message to appear in the logs in order to execute `Pattern.compile("Listening on:\\s+(https?)://\\S*:(\\d+)")` in CaptureListeningDataReader.

The failure happens because all the logs I see are:

```
2021-06-29 16:53:06,663 WARN  [io.qua.config] (main) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.ssl-port" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
2021-06-29 16:53:06,663 WARN  [io.qua.config] (main) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.port" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
...
2021-06-29 16:53:07,515 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) foo-authorizer-lambda 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 1.13.7.Final) started in 1.249s.
```

Perhaps I'm missing a plugin assumed to be present, thus the two WARN messages and a missing "Listening on:" in the logs?

Comment: What does your application do?

Comment: And when you run it in dev mode (or prod mode), what does the logging output look like?

Comment: Well, it turned out I was using the wrong annotation for what I needed to do (@QuarkusIntegrationTest instead of @QuarkusTest). I haven't investigated the matter further though